# Create a simple service in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a simple div that contains overlay with "loading" gif.

I want to be able to show/hide this "loader" and have it accessible through any controller.

I believe I need to use a service for that. this is my simple code which fail to work:

```
MyApp.factory('loader', function() {
    $(".loader").fadeIn();
 });
```

and then in **controllers.js**:

```
MyApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope, $auth, $state) {

    $rootScope.loader;

});
```

But this does nothing. I'm new to angular and I'd appreciate a direction to solve this.

I essentially want to create something like this:

loader.show();
loader.hide();

Of course if anyone think this should be done differently it would be great to hear a more efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ? When app is loaded it will show loader and after 1 sec loader will be hidden.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.showLoader = true;
 })

app.controller('Ctrl', function($rootScope, $timeout) {

  $timeout(function(){
   $rootScope.showLoader = false;
  },1000);
 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

 
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <img ng-if='showLoader' src='http://www.arabianbusiness.com/skins/ab.main/gfx/loading_spinner.gif'>
  
</body>
```

Comment: wow thanks for this. can you check my answer? i'd be happy to know which way is more efficient.

Comment: I have been using the above coded loader in many professional apps and I find it right way for loader becuaes its usually full-page so better not create service/factory for it, your style of answer will best fit if loader is just showing on some corner or not blocking screen or its toaster like thing.

Comment: Why does it matter if the UI is full screen or not? A factory can display it however he wants without adding to angulars global scope potentially causing conflicts and scope issues. $rootScope should very rarely be used.

Answer (score 1):

Uh i actually made it alone, im proud. here's the code for whoever come across this.

```
MyApp.factory('loader', function() {

    this.show = function(){
        // show loader code..
    }

    this.hide = function(){
        // hide loader code..
    }

    return this;

 });
```

**usage:**

```
loader.show/hide();
```

Comment: This is much better than the other answers to use $rootScope which just pollute the global scope, however there are some best practices you should include, see my answer for an example of how I would do this.

Answer (score 1):

To work with the DOM element you must use the [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). They are created for this.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/kvx7g92h/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleOneController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.loading2 = false;
    $scope.time1 = 1;
    $scope.time2 = 4;
    $scope.emulateRequest1 = function(time) {
      $scope.loading1 = true;
      console.log($scope.loading1,time);
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.loading1 = false;
        console.log($scope.loading1,time);
      }, time * 1000)
    };
    $scope.emulateRequest2 = function(time) {
      $scope.loading2 = true;
      console.log($scope.loading2,time);
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.loading2 = false;
        console.log($scope.loading2,time);
      }, time * 1000)
    };
  })
  .directive('loading', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        process: "="
      },
      template: '<div ng-show="process">Loading...</div>',
    }
  });;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
    <h3>
      ExampleOneController
    </h3>
    <form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
      <input ng-model="time1" placeholder="time in seconds">
      <button ng-click="emulateRequest1(time1)">
        Send emulate request
      </button>
      <br>
      <input ng-model="time2" placeholder="time in seconds">
      <button ng-click="emulateRequest2(time2)">
        Send emulate request 2
      </button>
      <loading process="loading1"></loading>
      <loading process="loading2"></loading>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

### UPDATED

Version with the factory. This solution is **wrong**.

If you send a first request that is performed for 4 seconds, then that runs for 1 second, you can see that with the loading div gone to request complete with 4 seconds. Look at `console`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/9tk07rac/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleOneController', function($scope, $timeout,LoadingService) {
    $scope.loadingService = LoadingService;
    $scope.loadingService.loading = false;
    $scope.time1 = 1;
    $scope.time2 = 4;
    $scope.emulateRequest = function(time) {
      $scope.loadingService.loading = true;
      console.log($scope.loadingService.loading,time);
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.loadingService.loading = false;
        console.log($scope.loadingService.loading,time);
      }, time * 1000)
    };
  })
  .service('LoadingService', function() {
    return {
      loading: false,
    }
  });;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
    <h3>
      ExampleOneController
    </h3>
    <form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
      <input ng-model="time1" placeholder="time in seconds">
      <button ng-click="emulateRequest(time1)">
        Send emulate request
      </button>
      <br>
      <input ng-model="time2" placeholder="time in seconds">
       <button ng-click="emulateRequest(time2)">
        Send emulate request 2
      </button>
      <div ng-show="loadingService.loading">
      loading...
      </div>
     <div ng-show="loadingService.loading">
      loading...
     </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working with a directive makes sense considering a template is involved here, however it's not necessary. The OP can create a factory, add a showLoader boolean on the factory and then use ng-if='showLoader' to show/hide the template.

Comment: There are several ways to solve a problem. But there are ways to solve that are preferred over others. For the manipulation of the **DOM** is better to use an element of the **directive**, which encapsulate the logic. In your proposal use the `factory` there is a problem. If you want to use two boot loader on the same page? In this case your solution is not clean.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a $rootScope variable in run function and set it default to true as

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
 .run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.showLoader = true;
 })
```

So whenever a page load it automatically show, now to hide it use

```
$rootScope.showLoader = false;
```

in your controller after you got the response from server or somewhere else

```
 MyApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope, $auth, $state) {

 $rootScope.showLoader = false;

});
```

And for loader, there is no need to use a service.

Comment: I posted an answer, mind to have a look? I was wondering, which way is better? FYI. you need to keep in mind that my loader is hidden by default through CSS.

Comment: You really shouldn't use $rootScope.

Comment: @efarley, suggest a better way & why.

Comment: See my answer below, you shouldn't use $rootScope because you're poluting the global scope which should be avoided, a better solution is to use a factory and inject that factory into a module/controller which is used for the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use $rootScope for this as it is using angulars global scope which should be avoided in almost all instances. You should use a factory to do this, you can then inject the factory into you parent module/controller and it will be available to your entire app. I suggest you modulize you code and include application wide methods such as this in a core module.

Here is a working example of how I would do this. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adQVjX

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', Ctrl) // Using a named function makes the code more readable and allows other devs to quickly see all of the dependencies in a quick glance at the top of the module
    .factory('loader', loader); // Let's create a loader factory which can contain any properties or methods associated with the loader.

  Ctrl.$inject = ['loader']; // Inject the factory into the controller.

  function Ctrl (loader) { 
    var ctrl = this; // This makes the rest of the code more readable and makes it clear what you are referencing in nested scopes.
    ctrl.showLoader = loader.showLoader; // Set up a method on the controller that calls the associated method on the loader factory. This is really only necessary if you want to call this method from the controllers scope.
    ctrl.hideLoader = loader.hideLoader; // ditto

    return ctrl;
  }

  function loader () {
    var loader = { // Create a loader object which has two methods defined.
      hideLoader: hideLoader,
      showLoader: showLoader
    };

    return loader; // Return our object to the controller.

    function hideLoader () {
      // Hide loader code goes here...
    }

    function showLoader () {
      // Show loader code goes here...
    }
  }
})();
```

You might use it something like this from a view, although you'll probably just call these methods from inside the controller.

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <body>
        <div>
          <div ng-controller='MyCtrl as ctrl'>
            <button ng-click='ctrl.showLoader()'>
              Show Loader
            </button>
            <button ng-click='ctrl.hideLoader()'>
              Hide Loader
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```